# Convert date and time to time stamp

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a text file ,want to open in python and take the date and time (in header) then change it to seconds (timestamp). but result is not the same as online websites. 
Code:

```
with open('sample for north - Kopie.txt', "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

    for x in content :
        day = float (content [0][:2])
        month = float (content [0][3:5])
        year = float (content [0][6:10])
        hour = float (content [0][10:13])
        minn = float (content [0][14:16])
        second = float (content [0][17:19])
        time = float ((((year-1970)*31556926)+((month-1)*2629743)+((day-1)*86400)+((hour)*3600)+((minn)*60)+second))
```

for *13.07.2015 09:38:17* result of program is *1436911625* but result of websites are *1436780297*.

Comment: What is `re`? Also, the file related code seems irrelevant to the question. Could you just create a function to process a line?

Comment: Are you accounting for leap years, etc?

Comment: @PeterWood I am really sorry. Corrected. I just found websites say that each year is 31556926 second and each month is 2629743 seconds and... and just put it in equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use time module:

```
import time

>>>print(time.mktime(time.strptime("13.07.2015 09:38:17", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))
1436769497.0
```

Comment: it is a good idea.but if you put the result in (http://www.epochconverter.com/) it give 07:38:17

Comment: It is because timestamp based on my computer time zone, and your computer on your time zone.

Comment: it is right. last question: if i want to ad the time exactly like website, what should i do?

Comment: You need to know website time zone and add or deduct difference from your timestamp

Comment: @mmachine: timestamp is not based on your computer time zone. `1436780297` corresponds to `2015-07-13T09:38:17Z` whatever your local time zone is. On the other hand, **the input time string**  may be interpreted differently: it may represent time in an arbitrary timezone. But if OP wants `1436780297` timestamp than it means that the input is in UTC (or some other timezone that has the zero utc offset at that time).

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts:

1. **Convert a time string into a time object in Python.** You could use `.strptime()` for that:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime

   dt = datetime.strptime("13.07.2015 09:38:17", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
   # -> datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 13, 9, 38, 17)
   ```
2. **Convert the time object into (POSIX) timestamp (Unix time).** `1436780297` result suggests that your input time is in UTC and therefore you could use `calendar.timegm()` to get the timestamp:

   ```
   from calendar import timegm

   timestamp = timegm(dt.timetuple())
   # -> 1436780297
   ```

See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)